# how can change system date time in ubuntu os with .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I tried to Change system date time in Linux based operating system, but in my search, I could't find any proper help,
Now, my Question is How can I change system date time with .net core2.2 in ubuntu OS?

Comment: I have same question !! anyone can help ??

Comment: This feels like an 
[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you clarify why you need this and what it is you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Just start a `Process` that calls `date` with the appropriate arguments?

Comment: In Linux, most people use ntpd.  Why do you need to change the time of the system in your application?

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search brings up a nice helper method for doing this...

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public static class ShellHelper
{
    public static string BashCommand(string cmd)
    {
        var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/bash",
                Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        return result;
    }
}
```

*Source: https://loune.net/2017/06/running-shell-bash-commands-in-net-core/*

then give it a call

```
string cmd = ""; // see below
ShellHelper.BashCommand(cmd);
```

You can get the bash command to change the date here...
https://www.garron.me/en/linux/set-time-date-timezone-ntp-linux-shell-gnome-command-line.html

> Note that this obviously won't work on a different operating system, so it is not cross-platform code. Make sure you handle these cases accordingly.